# How do I stop my note 4 from activating the screen when it is done charging?

Tags: charging, samsung-galaxy-note-4

When I charge it at night and its finished the screen will stay on all night unless I plug it out. How do I stop this from happening.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the Developer Options settings enabled on your phone? If you do, go to **Settings >> Developer Options >> Stay Awake**. If that option is checked, then your phone will never sleep while charging. Uncheck it.

Also, in **Settings >> Display >> Daydream >> When to Activate (at bottom)**,do  you have Daydream set to activate while charging? It's possible Daydream is triggering.

Answer (score -1):

Change the screen timeout option, or the 'Never sleep on charging' option

Comment: How does someone do this? Needs more detail.